# Error 3011 al exportar datos de access a excel

Tags: vba, ms-access

Buenas. Tengo un problema cuando intento generar un excel desde una tabla access (2010).
Tengo el siguiente código.

```
Dim outputFileName As String
Dim objExcel As Object 'New Excel.Application
Dim objWB As Object 'Workbook
'Nombre del archivo de salida
outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Salida\Cartelera_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & "_" & Format(Time, "HHmmss") & ".xlsx"
FileCopy CurrentProject.Path & "\PlantillaCartelera.xlsx", outputFileName

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(outputFileName)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "temp", outputFileName, False
objWB.ActiveSheet.Select
'objWB.Worksheets("Datos").Visible = False
'objExcel.Visible = True
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Cuando lo ejecuto aparece el siguiente mensaje de error

> Se ha producido el error '3011' en tiempo de ejecución:
>   El motor de la base de datos de Microsoft Office no pudo encontrar el objeto 'temp'. Asegúrese de que el objeto exista y que haya escrito el nombre y la ruta de acceso del objeto correctamente. Si 'temp' no es un objeto local, compruebe la conexión de red o póngase en contacto con el administrador del servidor.

La ruta está bien definida ya que si me crea el archivo excel donde quiero insertar la tabla "temp" y la tabla 'temp' si posee registros.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás indicando en `TransferSpreadsheet` con `temp` es una cadena de texto, sin más, lo tienes entrecomillado.

Tendrás que incluir el path completo:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "C:\user\dir\dir2\...", outputFileName, False
```

Tienes más información en la [web de msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff844793.aspx).

Comment: Por lo que creo y veo en la información que me has puesto debería ir así por ser una tabla,¿no?

Comment: TableName es opcional, si no lo has incluido antes como parámetro no es necesario que lo especifiques.

Comment: Al final no logré arreglarlo pero como los que querían la aplicación decidieron otra cosa pues nada. Gracias por la ayuda ;)